# Enter a new line after 4 commas in vim

Tags: vim

How do I enter a new line after every 4 commas in vim.

My data looks something like this.

```
0x0, 0x2, 0x5, 0x1, 0x4, 0x1, 0x8, 0x0, 0xca, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x0, 0x64, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x64, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x14, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2c, 0x0, 0x29, 0x1, 0x0, 0x5, 0x6, 0x4, 0x6, 0x5, 0x7, 0x3, 0x6, 0x2, 0x7, 0xd, 0x6, 0x4, 0x6, 0xf, 0x6, 0xc, 0x6, 0x5, 0x6, 0x4, 0x3, 0x0, 0x5, 0x1, 0x5, 0x3, 0x5, 0x9, 0x4, 0x3, 0x5, 0x1, 0x3, 0x2, 0x0, 0x1, 0x4, 0x3, 0x4,
```

I want to have it formatted so that every 4 comma's a new line is inserted, so that the data will look like this

```
0x0, 0x2, 0x5, 0x1, 
0x4, 0x1, 0x8, 0x0, 
0xca, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 
0xff, 0xfe, 0x0, 0x64, 
0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x64, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x14, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2c, 
0x0, 0x29, 0x1, 0x0, 
0x5, 0x6, 0x4, 0x6, 
0x5, 0x7, 0x3, 0x6, 
0x2, 0x7, 0xd, 0x6, 
0x4, 0x6, 0xf, 0x6, 
0xc, 0x6, 0x5, 0x6, 
0x4, 0x3, 0x0, 0x5, 
0x1, 0x5, 0x3, 0x5, 
0x9, 0x4, 0x3, 0x5, 
0x1, 0x3, 0x2, 0x0, 
0x1, 0x4, 0x3, 0x4,
```

I know that it can be done manually, but I have to do this 4-5 times a day and it is reaching the point where an easier solution is looked for.

Comment: Just a note that there's also a dedicated vi & vim sister site: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

```
s/\v([^,]+,){4}\zs /\r/g
```

- `\v` very magic, to avoid having to escape meta characters `({` etc
- `([^,]+,){4}\zs` non-comma characters followed by comma, repeated four times. Then `\zs` to mark start of match, saves the trouble of pasting what is captured so far in replacement section
- the space after 4th comma is replaced with newline
- `g` modifier to replace all such matches

You can map this substitute to work on current line to a key, say `F2` function key

```
nnoremap #2 :s/\v([^,]+,){4}\zs /\r/g<CR>
```

Any time you press `F2` in normal mode, the substitution will be performed

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

you can make a macro

on the first char in the line

qq4f,lr<kbd>Enter</kbd>@qq

qq starts a new macro called q.
4f, finds the forth `,`
l moves to the right of it
r<kbd>enter</kbd> replaces the space with an enter
@q calls the macro you have just made to recursively call it
q to finish recording

Then simple @q to format it.

q can be any letter

This gives me

```
0x0, 0x2, 0x5, 0x1, 
0x4, 0x1, 0x8, 0x0, 
0xca, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 
0xff, 0xfe, 0x0, 0x64, 
0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x64, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x14, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2c, 
0x0, 0x29, 0x1, 0x0, 
0x5, 0x6, 0x4, 0x6, 
0x5, 0x7, 0x3, 0x6, 
0x2, 0x7, 0xd, 0x6, 
0x4, 0x6, 0xf, 0x6, 
0xc, 0x6, 0x5, 0x6, 
0x4, 0x3, 0x0, 0x5, 
0x1, 0x5, 0x3, 0x5, 
0x9, 0x4, 0x3, 0x5, 
0x1, 0x3, 0x2, 0x0, 
0x1, 0x4, 0x3, 0x4,
```

When finished if you type `:reg`

there should be a line simiar to

```
"q   4f,lr^M@q
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.